# Split one row into multiple rows (fixed width)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

One row of incoming record has multiple sub-records concatenated. Each sub record is 9 characters long. I have 8 such sub-records in each row. So each row is (8x9=72 char). Is there a way i can split 1 record into 8 records here?

### Input

```
123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789
```

### Output

```
123456789 
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
123456789
```

I know i can do this with 8 sub queries and union them .. is there a better way?

Comment: If you need a really split oracle function, maybe you could like visit this link: [Oracle split](http://www.aprender-a-programar.com/funcion-split-en-oracle) Regards

Answer (score 2):

or how about this:

```
SELECT substr(t1.astr,n*9+1,9) 
FROM t1,
(SELECT ROWNUM-1 n FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8) t2
```

table t1 contains your strings, table t2 is a generated list of sequential numbers from 0 to 7 by cross joining it to the t1 table we can use it to cut up the string column.

Comment: Much better solution than mine on the iterator.  The substr needed to be changed a bit.  The following is tested and works:  select t2.n, substr('123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789',n*9+1,9) 
from dual,
(SELECT ROWNUM-1 n FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8) t2

Comment: cheers buddy, well spotted, have corrected, (Its about time I installed oracle on my linux server)

Comment: Any thoughts on how to do this in MySQL?

Comment: yes, you could think of t2 as a CROSS JOIN to a table that contains sequential numbers perhaps ?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen people use a secondary table containing only the values 1 through 8, then joining with that table. You can use the value to substring your record.

Something like

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(long_val, eight.value * 9, 9)
FROM mytable, eight
```

Note: Query untested, but I hope the idea gets across.

Comment: This is a good idea, maybe you can use ALL_OBJECTS view to generate necessary number of rows (by using rownum and defining the logic to create the desired number of rows)

Answer (score 1):

If it is predictable that each line will always split into a fixed number of lines, something like the following should be possible:

```
select  
    b.iterator,
    substr(a.mystring,b.iterator*9-8,9) as split
from

(select '123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789' as mystring from dual) a,
(select 1 as iterator from dual union
 select 2 as iterator from dual union
 select 3 as iterator from dual union
 select 4 as iterator from dual union
 select 5 as iterator from dual union
 select 6 as iterator from dual union
 select 7 as iterator from dual union
 select 8 as iterator from dual) b
```

EDIT: Kevin's iterator was simpler and better than my brute force version.  The b subquery shoud be (SELECT ROWNUM  as iterator FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8)